# Prove: If $g(A)$ is not scalar ($g(A) \neq \lambda I$) $\rightarrow$ $g(A)$ has no real eigenvalues for a given matrix and minimum polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $A \in M_{n x n} (\mathbb R)$ such that $m_A(x) = x^2 + 1$ (the minimum polynomial), and let $g \in \mathbb R[x]$. Prove: If $g(A)$ is not scalar ($g(A) \neq \lambda I$) $\rightarrow$ $g(A)$ has no real eigenvalues

I can't really find the connection. So if $m_A(X)$ is like that, it is obvious that it has no -real- eigenvalues, since the minimum polynomial includes all the roots of the characteristic polynomial. Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: You just pointed out that $A$ has no real eigenvalues but you didn't prove it holds for $g(A)$.

Comment: I think I should figure out what does applying a polynomial to a matrix do to its' minimum polynomial. Is that relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(x) = (x^2+1)p(x) + qx + r$ for some real polynomial $p$ and some real numbers $q$ and $r$. Then $g(A) = qA + rI$. If $g(A)$ is not a scalar matrix, then $q\neq0$.

Comment: Does $g(x)$ have to be in this form? If so, why? If not, why did you take this form?

Comment: @TheNotMe Do you know [Euclidean division of polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division_of_polynomials#Euclidean_division)?

Comment: I do, I just don't understand what the connection here. Why does $g(x)$ look like this?

Comment: @TheNotMe Divide $g(x)$ by $x^2+1$. Call the quotient $p(x)$. By Euclidean division, the degree of the remainder is a smaller than the degree of the divisor $x^2+1$, hence it must be of the form $qx+r$.

Comment: Haha, that I understand. I am more confused about why $g(x)$ has to have $(x^2 + 1)p(x)$ as an element.

Comment: @TheNotMe It doesn't. You can as well pick any nonzero polynomial, say, $x^3$. Then $g(x)=x^3p(x) + qx^2 + rx + s$ for some polynomial $p(x)$ and some numbers $q,r,s$. This is perfectly valid, but useless in our present context. In this question, we are given a minimal polynomial. It is natural to use it.

Comment: The point is, $m_A(x)$ annihilates $A$. Therefore we can use it to eliminate all higher-degree terms in $g(A)$ that evaluate to zero, and leave only a simpler, lower-degree remainder polynomial.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you take a SPECIFIC $g(x)$ then you haven't actually proved the theorem for any polynomial $g(x)$.

Comment: Hmm, what specific $g(x)$? I don't see anywhere in my answer have I assumed that $g(x)$ is any particular polynomial. (There *is* an assumption, though, namely, $g(A)$ is not a scalar multiple of $I$.)

Comment: If you declared $g(x) = (x^2+1)p(x) + qx + r$ and proved upon this then you proved it for only ***this*** specific polynomial.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. I didn't assume that $g(x)$ takes any particular form. On the contrary, it is a *necessary consequence* of Euclidean division of polynomial that $g(x)$ can be written in the form of $(x^2+1)p(x) + qx + r$. The coefficients of $p,q,r$ do depend on $g$, but the form $(x^2+1)p(x) + qx + r$ is always valid.

Answer (score 0):

Fact $(1)$(Can easily be proved by induction using $A^2=-I$):$A^{2k-1}=\epsilon _1A$ and $A^{2k}=\epsilon_2 I$, $\forall k\in \mathbb{N},\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\in\{1,-1\}$

Let $g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ix^i$($a_i\in R$)

Using Fact $(1)$ we have

$g(A)=aA+bI$($a,b\in R$ and clearly $a\ne 0$ for then $g(A)=bI$ which is impossible)

So if $g(A)$ has real eigen values it will imply ,

$(aA+bI)v=\lambda v$

$\Rightarrow A=\frac{(\lambda-b)}{a}v$ .This is impossible as $A$ doesnt have any real eigen value.

Comment: Weird. $m_A(A) = 0 = A^2 + I \rightarrow A^2 = -I$ and not $A^2 = -A$.

Comment: Now I think its ok.@TheNotMe